# Printing line from file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh

I have a **.txt** file which contains text.

```
Eks:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
End of file aka last line
```

How can I get print lines from the file and print them to the terminal using a bash script?

Is it possible to use a while loop to get line by line from the txt file and print them out ?

Comment: What info? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file, line by line, you can use this:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way, using `while` and `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cat to print the whole file,

```
cat a.txt
```

To choose a initial(use head) or end(use tail) bits/512-byte blocks/lines use flags -c/-b/-n respectively

```
cat a.txt | head -n 5
```

to read line by line,

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
done < file
```